# how to share 3g internet via wifi?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8, 3g

I have Windows 8 + 3g Vodafone modem.
I want to share internet via wifi so my friend can use it from mobile phone.

I've tried to use this instructions: http://www.techseeks.com/how-to-make-windows-8-laptop-a-wireless-access-point.html

1. I've set "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection". I've set "Home networking connection" to "WiFi".
2. I've executed C:\Windows\system32>NETSH WLAN SET HOSTEDNETWORK MODE = ALLOW SSID = MYW530 KEY
   = pwd

The hosted network mode has been set to allow.
The SSID of the hosted network has been successfully changed.
The user key passphrase of the hosted network has been successfully changed.

3. When I was tring to execute "C:\Windows\system32>NETSH WLAN START HOSTEDNETWORK" I receive such error:

The hosted network couldn't be started.
A device attached to the system is not functioning.

WiFi adapter is eneabled! Why network can not be started and how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps:

1. Disable and then Re-enable your WiFi adapter(Device Manager > Network Adapter > Wifi Adapter).
2. See if your Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter is turned on.
3. Check weather hosted network is supported by your wireless card. Type the following in cmd with administrator privileges: netsh wlan show drivers.If you find a line which says "Hosted Network Supported: Yes" only then you'll be able to create a hotspot.
4. Alternative to cmd you can use [Virtual Router](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/) or [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/) with gives GUI to manage your wireless hotspot.

Answer (score 0):

Check device manager for "Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter"  under Network Adapters.  If it is not there then step 2 didn't work.  Most likely you don't have permissions on your machine to set this up.